# This field is required error even after uploading the file

Tags: django

```
myview.py
def index_Expense(request):
    data=Expense.objects.all()
    form=ExpenseForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExpenseForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Expense/')
    return render_to_response('expense.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

mymodel.py

class Expense(models.Model):
    Expense_No=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Expense_Date=models.DateField(null=False)
    Amount=models.FloatField(null=False)
    Receipt=models.ImageField(upload_to='pic/',blank=False)
```

Using the above view i was trying to add a record using the form. When i click on add button i see the field is required error on the form for Receipt field even after i upload the file.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair.That is what i am exactly missing.Its working now.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Makes sure you have set up the `enctype` for your form in the template.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">
```

See the [docs on binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) for more info.